# clustering for categorical data with one column for observations

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, algorithms, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to cluster a dataset using 4 variables, all of which are categorical variables. I'd also like to include another numerical variable that's actually the number of observations of another column. My data is laid out like below:

ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE

where ColE would be the frequency of ColD; and all Columns A-D are categorical variable.
I don't want to use a supervising learning technique because of various reasons (the top one being I don't know what my result should be; only that I want to have k number of groups that are similar enough).
What's the best clustering algorithm to use for this? I've been thinking k-modes but that doesn't solve the problem of ColE being a feature of ColD.

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example of your data record. Especially the relationship of D and E seems to be unclear somehow.

Comment: Sure, so the dataset looks like this: with Color being ColD and Frequency being ColE: Item    |   Season | Type  |   Color| Frequency
Clothing| Summer| Suit| Navy| 2
Clothing| Summer| Suit| Black|  3
Clothing| Summer| Suit| Grey | 3

Comment: Sorry, the formatting here is confusing me a little bit. But the column E is a frequency column that denotes the number of observation for all the characteristics. I want a clustering of "like" ColA based on the characteristics of columns B, C, D and E but want to use unsupervised learning algorithm. thanks!

Comment: You can apply Multiple correspondence analysis (MCA) to your dataset, then apply appropriate clustering algorithms accordingly.

Comment: There are some answers to this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29771355/4752675) Also check out [Modified Value Distance Metric](https://axon.cs.byu.edu/papers/wilson.aie96.ivdm.pdf) and variants

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encoding the categorical variables into numeric?
http://fastml.com/converting-categorical-data-into-numbers-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn/

I would recommend starting with maybe two variables to apply K-modes and then iterate/increase the number of variables from there, as you analyze the results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Dummy variables doesn't work in my case because you end up vastly increasing the problem size- my categorical values have many values (~1000 in one case) so I'd need to add 999 new columns just to get that one column. The categorical vars part of the problem is solved using k-means/k-prototypes. My main problem is dealing with a dependent numeric variable (frequency count of each observation) - where I want the frequency of the observation to matter as well.

Comment: @sudhareg: This is important information, and should have been added as an edit and not only as comment!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only categorical variables, I would suggest to select a distance function (Hamming, Chi2,...), calculating the distance matrix between each observation, and then running a good old hierarchical clustering algorithm. You should try several distance functions to find the one giving the most meaningful results.